# How do i join 2 strings the right way

Tags: python, string

My problem is that this code only prints out "a"

```
print(str(random.randint(1, 2)).join(str("a")))
```

Comment: How exactly do you want it to print?

Comment: To concatenate strings yo should use + operator: `print('str' + 'str')` or template strings to format the output`print(f'{var_or_expression} {var_orexpression}')`.

Comment: `str(random.randint(1, 2))` is either `"1"` or `"2"`... the first argument of `join` should be an iterable (and not just the string `"a"`).

Comment: join accepts iterable
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join
For example. 
`print('-'.join(['1', '2', '3']))` will return `1-2-3`

Comment: I would suggest reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Answer (score 0):

`join` is used to concatenate elements of an iterable.
What you need is the `+` operator, so:

```
print(str(random.randint(1, 2))+"a")
```

You also don't need to cast `"a"` to string (it is a string already).

Answer (score 0):

`.join()` does not do what you think it does. What I think you actually want is string **concatenation**, which is done using the `+` operator. Also, the `str()` around `"a"` is unnecessary as it is already a string.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
import random
print(str(random.randint(1, 2)) + "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method):

```
>>> import random

>>> '{}a'.format(random.randint(1, 2))
'1a'
```

Answer (score -1):

i didn't get what actually but:
`a='test'`
`print(str(random.randint(1, 2)).join(str(" a")))'`
output : `t2e2s2t`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).